# Chrome dev tools workspace, view changes in browser on refresh

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

If I map resources on the remote server to corresponding files in my Chrome dev tools workspace, and refresh the page, should I expect to see those changes when the page reloads?

Because right now, I am making changes, and not seeing them when I refresh.

As a sanity test, I mapped my styles.css on my blog to a blank styles.css in my dev tools workspace, but when I refreshed the page, all the styling was still evident.

Am I expecting something that the dev tools cannot do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to attempt here? Are you saying you're loading a remote site, and expecting dev tools to ignore the css it gets from the remote webserver, and use something local instead? That seems like a backwards way to accomplish dev work. Why not just create a dev installation of your blog and edit away?

Comment: @mituw16, forget that I mentioned my blog then, and imagine a large enterprise site, which cannot easily be run as a local instance at present, and you may see my real use case.

Comment: I see. Is there no dev environment for this enterprise site? If you want persistent CSS changes, I think you will need to look into something like http://stylebot.me/about

Comment: @mituw, yup. Just want to work quickly without having to FTP to the dev environment so often. I already have some workarounds, but wanted to move even faster. Thanks for the link.

Comment: In case anybody who comes across this question needs some background on Chrome dev tools workspaces, here you go. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/revolutions2013/#toc-workspaces

Comment: Whenever I want to use Workspaces in Google Chrome Devtools, this is always the exact use case I assume it supports, but every time I'm disappointed it doesn't. How is this not a feature?

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces

If you are mapping files from a remote server instead of a local server, when you refresh the page, Chrome reloads the page from the remote server again. Your changes still persist to disk and are reapplied if you continue editing in Workspaces.